# grep a single word from multiple results

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a shell script to monitor file system. script logic is,
for each file system from `df -H` command, read the file system threshold file and get the critical threshold, warning threshold. Based on the condition, it will send notification.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
df -H | grep -vE '^Filesystem|none|boot|tmp|tmpfs' | awk '{ print $5 " " $6 }' | while read $output
do
echo $output
fsuse=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1  )
fsname=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $2 }' )
server=`cat /workspace/OSE/scripts/fs_alert|grep -w $fsname|awk -F":" '{print $2}'`
fscrit=`cat /workspace/OSE/scripts/fs_alert|grep -w $fsname|awk -F":" '{print $3}'`
fswarn=`cat /workspace/OSE/scripts/fs_alert|grep -w $fsname|awk -F":" '{print $4}'`
serenv=`cat /workspace/OSE/scripts/fs_alert|grep -w $fsname|awk -F":" '{print $5}'`
if [ $fsuse -ge $fscrit ]; then
   message="CRITICAL:${server}:${serenv}:$fsname Is $fsuse Filled"
   _notify;
elif [ $fsuse -gt $fswarn ] && [ $fsuse -lt $fscrit ]; then
    message="WARNING: $fsname is $fsuse Filled"
    _notify;
else
    echo "File system space looks good"
fi
done
```

Here is `/workspace/OSE/scripts/fs_alert`:

```
/:hlpdbq001:90:80:QA:dba_mail
/dev/shm:hlpdbq001:90:80:QA:dba_mail
/boot:hlpdbq001:90:80:QA:dba_mail
/home:hlpdbq001:90:80:QA:dba_mail
/opt:hlpdbq001:90:80:QA:dba_mail
/opt/security:hlpdbq001:90:80:QA:dba_mail
/tmp:hlpdbq001:90:80:QA:dba_mail
/var:hlpdbq001:90:80:QA:dba_mail
/u01/app:hlpdbq001:90:80:QA:dba_mail
/u01/app/oracle:hlpdbq001:90:80:QA:dba_mail
/oratrace:hlpdbq001:90:80:QA:dba_mail
/u01/app/emagent:hlpdbq001:90:80:QA:dba_mail
/gg:hlpdbq001:90:80:QA:dba_mail
/workspace:hlpdbq001:90:80:QA:dba_mail
/dbaudit:hlpdbq001:90:80:QA:dba_mail
/tools:hlpdbq001:90:80:QA:dba_mail
```

My problem is when the script is trying to get `crit_va`, `warn_val` from the file for `/u01` file system, I am getting three results. How do I get/filter one file system at a time?

```
$ df -H|grep /u01
/dev/mapper/datavg-gridbaselv    53G   12G   39G  24% /u01/app
/dev/mapper/datavg-rdbmsbaselv   53G  9.6G   41G  20% /u01/app/oracle
/dev/mapper/datavg-oemagentlv    22G  980M   20G   5% /u01/app/emagent
```

what is the best way to handle this issue? 
do i need logic based on `Filesystem` or `Mounted on`.

Comment: How does your desired output look like?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `while read output`?

Comment: i need to check each file system used space and compare used space is greater than threshold value defined in " /workspace/OSE/scripts/fs_alert" if any file system used space more than the threshold defined on the file, then send alert.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel. There are tools out there that can do this for your. Try monit for example:

http://sysadminman.net/blog/2011/monit-disk-space-monitoring-1716

Answer (score 0):

well, monit is fine ), if you need alternative take a look at [df-check](https://sparrowhub.org/info/df-check?v=0.000006) - a wrapper for df utility to verify that thresholds are not exceeded , on per partition basis. At least it seems very close to what you started to implement in your bash script, but it's written on perl and has a neat and simple installation layout. ready to use tool.

-- Regards

PS discloser - I am the tool author